# Selecting a Language for desktop application

Tags: java, c, visual-c++, desktop-application

I have an idea and want to build a desktop application

Requirements: Open Source, portable, cross platform, easy to install, easy to make setup, simple GUI, high speed draft printing.

I have some options:

1. Java : easy to make jar file but don’t know how to make setup executable, swing is easy to implement
2. C#: Easy to make setup file but tools for open source are limited, difficult to implement
3. Python: Python eggs are setup file, difficult to make interface, is easy to develop, fast programmable
4. Ruby: Don’t know anything about ruby
5. C/C++ : I had used C builder and Codelite product in C and C++, it is difficult to work with crafter widgets
6. Visual Basic: Easy to build nice GUI but portability, reporting and setup issues
7. Visual Fox Pro: Microsoft open sourced version but database support is limited to sql and Microsoft Access
8. and other: Don’t know much about other languages

I want

1. An Application setup should be fast and easy to create
2. Easy to build GUI not like C++ crafter or any other external source
3. Multiple options for open source reporting tools
4. And it could run on different platforms: Linux,Windows 7/8 and others

Please, can you suggest me a language or any other resources and links that could help me to find the best solution.

I want to know how desktop applications are made from start to end in open source.

When I see setup of applications I download for various needs of requirement it doesn't speaks how it developed and what language is used for it...but its beautiful to use it..

Comment: How about you try some of these option yourself and then decide what works best for you?

Comment: If there were a single best language or tool, everyone would use that and you wouldn't have to ask. Now there isn't.

Comment: I don't know should I suggest you a specific language or not. But IMO Java or Qt/C++ can satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I have tried with java swing but not able to create setup of JAR ,with C++ its difficult to buid GUI,and with python it dont creates an exe to run directly it creates an python egg lik java creates JAR ...did u know easy to create setup open source tool in setup.exe

Answer (score 2):

Python and WxPython is used throughout the DropBox project to implement cross platform GUI. Bittorrent was also first implemented in python.

So I would advocate Python. - Easy deployment option with py2exe and py2app

If you really don't mind Qt and C++ then that would be an option as well or C++ with WxWidgets

Comment: Is Python can make exe file directly without creating python eggs?

Comment: python creates .exe files that enclose the python interpreter - I don't know what eggs you're talking about :-P

Comment: @user1581768 py2exe creates an executable. Not an egg. The downside is the whole python interpreter is shipped with your application. This is how dropbox deploys to your end.

Comment: Before python 2.7 release in python there is no executable file creator tool now it have added in later versions thanks ankit